# Exhaustion method blocked by religious aspects?

Tags: ancient-greece, 16th-century

Eudoxus developed the exhaustion method for calculating areas that continued with Archimedes and then only in the 16th century with Simon Stevin and Buonaventura Cavalieri. Why did it take so long? Was there any mystical restriction due to the fact that the method was based on the concept of infinity?

Comment: There was no restriction. People discussed infinity all this time. But the progress in mathematics and science was not continuous. There was a strong decline for about 1500 years in the development. This applies not only to mathematics but to science as well.

Comment: How can you explain that this method is not used for centuries ? even though this method is so useful to calculate areas and volumes

Comment: The reason is simple: in those centuries nobody read advanced parts of Euclid or anything by Archimedes. Very few people at all cared about mathematics. This was what they used to call "collapse of civilization". Now this term is out of fashion, but collapse really did happen, at least in science and engineering.

Comment: There are some claims that the pope used the conceivable conflict of "atomic theory" with "transubstantiation" as an excuse to persecute Galileo (and others). Supposedly, if one wants to pick at it, the ideas about matter that might make "the method of indivisibles [etc]" legitimate might suggest that, since the nature of matter is fixed at a very small level, transubstantiation is impossible. That kind of thing. In Galileo's case, I have the impression that that kind of argument was more an excuse to punish a miscreant than a profound expression of philosophical points.

Comment: see also this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/661999/442

Comment: Aristotle wrote of a *horror vacui* or horror of the void as expressed in surds like *pi* and hypothetical vacuums. This may be a key source for Western civ's reluctance to engage with the concept of infinity.   https://www.jstor.org/stable/40231690  Marcus du Satoy writes of it as representing the advance of scientific and technical progress insofar as successively less crude, more precise estimates were made. https://www.google.com/books/edition/How_to_Count_to_Infinity/r2PyDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: I don't know how you can claim that "There was no restriction. People discussed infinity all this time."  The famous distinction between potential and actual infinity, usually attributed to Aristotle, was a significant obstacle to progress because it declared actual infinity to be incoherent (and possibly contradictory).

Answer (score 2):

Cavalieri did not use the method of exhaustion, but rather an alternative (and easier) approach using indivisibles.  In the Counter-Reformation context, there was fierce opposition to both mathematical and physical indivisibles.  Cavalieri and his student Degli Angeli published a number of books on indivisibles, which were criticized by several jesuit scholars (Guldin, Tacquet, Bettini).  Both Cavalieri and Degli Angeli were jesuats (with an "a").  Cavalieri's religious order of the jesuats was suppressed by papal bull in 1668.  Some scholars relate the suppression to the scientific activities of Cavalieri and Degli Angeli that was viewed with suspicion by influential elements at Rome.